# Replace + (Plus) Character using a New Line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have column which has a long string with multiple sentences. Each sentence is separated by a plus (+) character. For an example: 1. This is line one + 2. This is line two + 3. This is line Four

Now I would like to replace the plus (+) character by a new line. Using T-SQL how can I get the output like:

1. This is line one
2. This is line two
3. This is line three

Comment: What's the *real* problem? Why do that with T-SQL? Why not let the *client* do this? You won't be able to display newlines in an HTML page for example, you'd need to use page breaks. That's something the client knows about, not the server

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) doesn't work with T-SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `REPLACE` and replace the `+` character with a carriage return and line break:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(YourString,'+', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS YourString
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```